# RandomRotation error when using Dataset.map

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to do some data augmentation. For some reason I get an error when using RandomRotation in Dataset.map (The code works fine if I do data_augmentation() without mapping but rather just in the target network). The RandomFlip and RandomConstrast functions seem to be working just fine.

I'm curious why it doesn't work, but I'd also appreciate any workaround just for rotation.

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
    # layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(factor=0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
])

def augmentation(image,label):
    image=data_augmentation(image)
    return image,label


ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train= ds_train.map(augmentation,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Traceback:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    693       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    694         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 695           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    696         else:
    697           raise
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (sequential_29/random_rotation_6/rotation_matrix/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the error happens, but ImageDataGenerator provides the same functionalities and is a more popular way to use data augmentation.

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      vertical_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator = generator.flow_from_directory(
    "faces2",
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    batch_size=32,
    save_to_dir="augmented"
)
```